# Log4Net in Web API .Net Core

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, asp.net-core-7.0

I'm a C# beginner. In my Web Api, I want to each service will log to specific log file using Log4net. In my log4net.config file, I setup like below.

In my service class, after I injected ILogger<> to class constructor, how can I set the right appender for it? like servceA class will go to serviceA appender. And if I don't set appender for ILogger<>, I want it automatically use DefaultAppender.

How can I setup log4net like that? please help :(

```
<log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" /> 
  </root>
  <logger name="Default">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="Default" />
  </logger>
  <logger name="ServiceA">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="ServiceA" />
  </logger>
  <logger name="ServiceB">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="ServiceB" />
  </logger>


  <appender name="Default" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="_Logs\Default\" />
    <datePattern value="dd.MM.yyyy'.events.log'" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
    <maximumFileSize value="20MB" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="[%date] [%level] %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="ServiceA" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="_Logs\SessionLog\ServiceA\" />
    <datePattern value="dd.MM.yyyy'A.events.log'" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
    <maximumFileSize value="20MB" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="[%date] [%level] %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="ServiceB" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="_Logs\SessionLog\ServiceB\" />
    <datePattern value="dd.MM.yyyy'B.events.log'" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
    <maximumFileSize value="20MB" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="[%date] [%level] %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

</log4net>
```

Comment: Without DI you can setup it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154048/log4net-how-to-add-a-2nd-logger-used-only-for-specific-sections-of-code

Comment: yes, I did try that :D, but is there any way using DI to setup multiple appenders?